# Minecraft Forge 1.7.10: WorldEvent.load not working?

Tags: java, loading, minecraft-forge

I have an eventhandler class where I am trying to chat a message to the server chat, once it is loaded, however, the WorldEvent.Load never seems to get called! Code:

```
package com.dropthevase.motdchanger;

import cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer;
import net.minecraft.util.ChatComponentText;
import net.minecraftforge.event.world.WorldEvent;

public class EventHandler {

 @SubscribeEvent
    public void onLoad(WorldEvent.Load event)
    {
        System.out.println("testing");
        MinecraftServer.getServer().addChatMessage(new ChatComponentText("MOTDChanger started."));
    }
}
```

Comment: You have used `EventBus.register` with this handler, right?

Comment: No, how do I do that?

Comment: Please make sure you read [official documentation](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events/intro/) before you declare that something doesn't work or is broken.